# What happened to the old Facebook Fan Pages?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to create a few funny campaigns like these:

- http://somerandomstuff1.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/100-funny-facebook-pages-to-like/

Is this the place to do it? It seems to be for company only and I can't seem to add funny titles:

- http://www.facebook.com/advertising/?pages

Answer (score 2):

You can create Facebook Pages by using this link

http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php

Facebook Pages has been upgraded so your page may look different to older pages (see changes below).

Taken from [this Facebook Help Article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19849)

- Photos at the top: The most recent photos that you post to the Wall of a Page you admin, or photos you tag your Page in, will appear here. This area will not include any photos posted by people who like your Page.
- Use Facebook as your Page: You will be able to receive notifications for your Page, view a News Feed for your Page, and like and post on other Pages as your Page.
- Wall filters: Pages now have two publicly visible Wall filters-"Posts by Page" and "Everyone." When viewing a Page Wall with the "Everyone" filter, the most engaging posts will appear at the top (i.e., posts will not appear in chronological order). Page admins will be able to view additional filters-"Most Recent" and "Hidden Posts."
- Email notifications: You can opt to receive notifications when people post or comment on your Page.
  Featured Pages and admins: You can feature other Pages your Page likes, or admins of your Page, in the new "Likes" and "Page Owners" sections on the left side of your Page.
- Mutual connections: When people visit your Page, they will be able to view friends who also like your Page, as well as other Pages that both they and your Page like.
- Navigation: The content that you formerly accessed by clicking the tabs at the top of your Page can now be found in the column underneath your Page profile picture. The text in the box that used to appear in the box underneath your Page profile picture will now appear in the Info tab.
- Profile picture size: The profile picture size for Pages has been adjusted from 200x600 to 180x540.